# Query events from native calendar that my app created

Tags: android, kotlin, android-calendar

I have an app which I can create events for native android calendar with. I want to query all events from native calendar that my app created and show them in list. I only know how to query all possible events in native calendar.

```
fun readCalendarEvent() {
    val dummyEvents = mutableListOf<DummyEvent>()
    val cursor: Cursor? = context.contentResolver.query(
        CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI,
        arrayOf("calendar_id", "title", "description", "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation"),
        null,
        null,
        null
    )
    cursor?.let {
        while (it.moveToNext()) {
            val calendarId = it.getString(0)
            val title = it.getString(1)
            val description = it.getString(2)
            val dtStart = it.getString(3)
            val dtEnd = it.getString(4)
            val eventLocation = it.getString(5)
            val dummyEvent = DummyEvent(
                calendarId, title, description, dtStart, dtEnd, eventLocation
            )
            dummyEvents.add(dummyEvent)
        }
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "readCalendarEvent: $dummyEvents")
}
```

This is code for adding events in native calendar:

```
fun insertEventInNativeCalendar(eventEntity: EventEntity) {
    val calId: Long = 1
    val recurringRule = getRecurringRule(repetition = eventEntity.repetition)

    val values = ContentValues().apply {
        put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, eventEntity.startTime.timeInMillis)
        put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, eventEntity.endTime.timeInMillis)
        put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, eventEntity.title)
        put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, eventEntity.description)
        put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, eventEntity.location)
        put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR, eventEntity.color.toString())
        put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calId)
        put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, eventEntity.isAllDay.toInt())
        if (!recurringRule.contains("NEVER")) {
            put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, recurringRule)
        }
        put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().id)
    }


    context.contentResolver.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values)
}
```